# Why is the Media module ignoring view_mode display settings?

Tags: media

I'm using the Media module 7.x-2.

I've added an image field to a content type, and I've enabled the Media CKEditor/Wysiwyg plug in and filter.
I've added fields to the image media/file type and set these up to display for the 'large' view mode setting.
When using the field, the image is displayed along with the other fields, as normal, but when I've inserted the image via Wysiwyg, only the image comes through; the fields are not displayed.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported in Media module. There is work being done though. Checkout this issue. https://drupal.org/node/1792738